# Having problems formatting Strings to a specific precision

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I am trying to format a string and write it into a file. See my code below

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.insert(0, String.format("%-30s", recDataWithWarId.getRiaFirmName() != null ? recDataWithWarId.getRiaFirmName() : " "));
```

The conditions I would like to achieve are (I already have a handle on condition 1 mentioned below):

1. If `recDataWithWarId.getRiaFirmName()` is not thirty characters in length or null I want to fill up rest of spaces with blank spaces.
2. I would also like to limit `recDataWithWarId.getRiaFirmName()` to 30 if the length is greater than 30 and which I had hoped this code would do automatically.

What is the most efficient way of achieving these two conditions without having to write lengthy code one for substring and one to format? I have to do it on multiple place as this is a fairly large text file.

Comment: write a function using substrings. Even if it longer code doesnt mean it is slower.

Comment: And on the same note: don't try to do too many things in one line of code, it doesn't make you look smarter and it's definitely harder to read, maintain and debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify both a precision and a width in your format string.  You want `"%-30.30s"`

The first `-30` specifies that the value will be padded on the right to 30 characters.  The `30` after the decimal point specifies the maximum number of characters.

Comment: Thanks @David Wallace. This was the bingo answer I was looking for.